# Does there exist a full, "Director's Cut" version of Fast Times at Ridgemont High?

Tags: alternate-version, fast-times-ridgemont-high

I remember watching this on TV many, many moons ago (maybe early 90's?) and there was a scene where Spiccoli is explaining how he got a guitar pick from Mick Jagger.  It was definitely not in the theatrical release, and at the time I just assumed they dug up deleted scenes to fill the timeslot because a **lot** of that movie had to be cut to be shown on American TV.  There were other scenes too, but I can't recall them as clearly.

So, does anyone know if all those scenes were ever placed back in the movie chronologically for a blu-ray/DVD "Director's Cut" release?  They were obviously finished scenes, not grainy or with bad audio like sometimes you see on a deleted scenes reel as a DVD extra.

Just in case you're not sure what I'm talking about, [here's the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eO3BVkbmXvg).  This was clearly extended, because in the theatrical release they walk in, pull out their change and then Hamilton points out the "No Shirts, No Shoes, NO DICE!" sign.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to say **no**.

Firstly, [on this IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083929/alternateversions), some of the differences between the versions are listed. The scene you refer to is described:

> In the original television version, there is more dialogue in the "no
>   shirt, no shoes, no dice" scene. Spicoli says "I have uno
>   nickel-ette...and a pick". He then makes up a story of how Mick Jagger
>   gave him that pick.

However, a quick pop over to Amazon shows one of the highest reviews saying the following:

> I can't believe the director of this movie keeps standing for the out
>   and out censorship of this! It's (at least) the third release of it on
>   DVD, and this latest (Nov. 2004) try is still a dud. The big problem
>   remains the scenes which they only include in the cable TV versions of
>   this, but keep cutting from the DVD. Why the heck do they?
>
> One of the missing scenes is a very cool safe sex/birth control scene
>   in the mall, for instance. Fast Times sticks out as one of the very
>   rare films that this odd censorship has been performed on. In fact,
>   out of thousands of releases since DVDs started in 1995, this is
>   almost the only one this has ever happened to!
>
> So again we can only ask why? WHY?

Now, that review was written in 2005, so is nearly 9 years old. But a quick traipse through the comments shows that discussions *about* the review have been raging ever since, with the most recent actually being posted in July 2014. The comments are mostly written by fans of the movie, such as yourself, who are wanting to know why extra scenes have not made it in to the DVD release.

There's also quite a few other forums online (e.g. [here](http://forums.stevehoffman.tv/threads/fast-times-at-ridgemont-high.291900/) and [here](http://archinect.com/forum/thread/103072/discrepencies-with-fast-times-at-ridgemont-high-screenplay-and-actual-movie)) to name just a very few where discussions have raged over what is different in the versions and why they haven't been released.

Given all this discussion, it seems **certain** to me that the full version, with all scenes intact has never been released.

On a final note, it may interest you to know that [there is a petition](http://www.petitiononline.com/ft1982/petition.html) going to have the full version released - unfortunately, as the time of writing, it only has 16 signatures...

Comment: This blows, because at this point they're not even showing it on cable anymore since it's so old, so I can't even record it and splice it myself.

Comment: UPDATE: There has been (as of May 2021) an official Criterion Collection release that includes both the movie version and the TV version.  So, while this answer is still valid, you can now get ahold of both versions commercially.

Answer (score 0):

It's not meant to be a "full" version. It is an alternate version. They added the new scenes to replace the stuff they couldn't show on television. I've heard that some of the scenes were done in reshoots for the TV version